# Ajax Call Success callback time is more than network call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, debugging

I'm trying to understand the reason about why the time of an ajax call that shows up 96ms is the network tab when checked via applying console.time logs before starting and getting the result in success callback is 239ms.

```
console.time('collections');
        ApiBridge.fetchCollections()
            .then((res) => {
                console.timeEnd('collections');
                dispatch(AppActions.hideLoader());
                dispatch(CollectionActions.setViewCollections(res));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                dispatch(AppActions.handleError());
            })
```

What's more alarming is it's fluctuating as high as 1500ms.
I'm using fetch api in this case, but I'm able to notice the same thing with any of the ajax libraries including jQuery.ajax and Angular's $http.

[image]

Can someone explain me the reason why this is happening and what can be done to reduce this time. Because the backend calls are taking lesser time actually and it's something happening on front-end.

Comment: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.  --[Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)

Comment: @kermani I've tried using performance.now and logging by using new Date().getTime difference too but still I'm able to observe the same thing.

Comment: it is possible if the collection is large enough to get some delay because of the parsing that takes place after the json has been received.

Comment: I agree with @Akis , you can see the DOMContentLoaded and Load time at the bottom of the browser

Comment: The data isn't that long. It's little json. Also, I checked with some simple mock json too, I'm seeing the same trend.

Comment: @ParamSingh it would be great if you can create a JSfiddle recreating the problem you have. I am sure you are going to get more help than that